# If for every epsilon there is a delta such that: $x,y<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt\varepsilon$, does the limit at $0$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

More formally, if given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta$ satisfying $x,y<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$, does $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ exist? I'm trying to figure out the best way to prove it, and it seems like it would either use a proof by contradiction, or somehow incorporate the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: Does $\delta$ have to be bigger than $0$?  Not true if $f(x) =-1; x \le 0$ and $f(x) = 1; x > 0$.  then for any $\epsilon > 0$ then $x,y, < 0 =\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)| = 0 < \epsilon$.  But limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You can first observe that  $(f(\frac 1 n))$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $l$ be the limit of this sequence.Then use the inequality $|f(x)-l| \leq |f(x)-f(\frac 1 n)|+|f(\frac 1 n)-l|$ to show that $f(x) \to l$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then there is a $\delta$ so that $x,y < \delta$ will imply $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Case 1:  $\delta > 0$.  Then $|x -0|<\delta \implies |x| < \delta \implies x < \delta$.  and $0< \delta$ so $|f(x) -f(0)| < \epsilon$.

Case 2: $\delta\le 0$. Well, okay.  Suppose $f(x) = c$ for all $x < \delta$ but $x \ge  0$ let $f(x)$ be something nasty and discontinuous at $x=0$ say $f(x)= c$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=d\ne c$.  Not continuous at $x =0$.

(But presumably $\delta$ in that condition is supposed to be positive....)